# MVC 5 Form, how can I return the page I am on once a formsubmit action has been completed?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a contactform which appears on two pages, when the form is submitted the FormSubmit action occurs, which looks as follows:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ActionResult> FormSubmit(contactform model)
{
    var current = Request.Url.OriginalString;
    var response = Request["g-recaptcha-response"];
    string secretKey = "keygoeshere";
    var client = new WebClient();
    var result = client.DownloadString(string.Format("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={0}&response={1}", secretKey, response));
    var obj = JObject.Parse(result);
    var status = (bool)obj.SelectToken("success");
    ViewBag.Message = status ? "Google reCaptcha validation success" : "Please click on the recaptcha";

    if (ModelState.IsValid && status)

    {
        try
        {

            var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Message:</p><p>{2}</p>";
            var message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("emailaddresshere"));
            message.Subject = "Contact Us";
            message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FirstName, model.LastName, model.number);
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                return RedirectToAction("Sent");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }
    }

    else
    {
        return View("What goes here?");

    }
```

The form checks the recaptcha and then validates the fields using the model 'contactform'.  If the recaptcha is not filled out or the validation fails the result is currently 'return View();', which will attempt to return the action 'Formsubmit', which doesn't return anything because this isn't a view.

That's how I understand it anyway.  What I would like to do is for the action above to be aware of which page the form is being submitted on and return the view of that specific page.  I can put in the individual page and return view there but then that means I need two separate 'formsubmit' actions or the likes, one for each page.  Is there a way I can return view to the page the form is being submitted on?

Also whilst I am here, I would like to ask if anyone knows how I can maintain the same position on the page when I am returning that view and validation has failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what your doing, but if I had to guess, the most logical thing is that you have a contact form in the actual layout, so it's on every page, but you have just one action to handle the post.

If that's the case, the best thing to do is to include a hidden field in the form with a return URL:

```
@Html.Hidden("returnUrl", Request.RawUrl)
```

That will always be filled with the current URL. Then, in your post action, you can utilize this to send the user back to where they were when they submitted the form.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> FormSubmit(contactform model, string returnUrl)
{
    ...

    if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Fallback");
}
```

The problem you're going to have with this when there's an error in the form, such as the captcha being invalid. There's no way to redirect back and maintain the form state, and you cannot simply return the view from that original page from this action. Presumably, different pages will use different models, need different initialization, etc. It's simply untenable to compensate for all the potential differences in on action.

One option is to have an actual view for this form. Then, on error, you return the standard contact view. This means the form will be redisplayed on it's own rather than as part of your layout, but then, all model state is maintained and the user can correct any errors and continue. By including the return URL hidden field (which now will need to be set based on what was passed to the action rather than `Request.RawUrl`), you can still redirect the user back to the original page after they finally do a successful post.

Honestly, if you want to have a form as part of your layout, and you want to keep the user on the same page, it's best to just submit it via AJAX.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, I have tried your solution and as it stands it just returns me to the 'fallback' page I set.  I added the @html hidden part tot he top of the contactform itself which is rendered on the two pages.  I then added the 'string returnURL' parameter to the formsubmit and the if statement where my return View() used to be.  It doesn't appear to be returning me to the same page?

Comment: I actually made an error, following your instructions does exactly what you said it would.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to put your form partial on any page and post to this action method. if any validation error occurs you want to return the control to the that page where the form has posted data from. if i am correct then

Please try->`@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "controller", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) {...` on your view

and

```
FormSubmit(contactform model, string returnUrl){your code; return Redirect(returnUrl);}
```

you can find the implementation in AccountController which is created by default in mvc template.

Comment: Hello, I've tried your solution but I receive an error message stating that the 'returnURL' can't be empty.  I amended my code exactly as you instructed above.  Have I missed something out?  Thanks

Comment: Hello Rob, please download a sample from here-> https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-jg0j7M5PfERS1NZXJybVlWQkk     I have implemented it in raw way. maybe you can do it better than me :)

Comment: It would be better if you use ajax for this.